# No free lunch with bounded and vanishing risk

Tags: options, option-pricing, arbitrage, no-arbitrage-theory

I am reading a book which states 'No free lunch with bounded risk as follows

[image]

where $\tilde{V}_t$ is the discounted value of the portfolio.Then it states the following theorem

[image]

EMM is the equivalent martingale measure.

But Wikipedia states the same theorem in the following way
[image]

Does this mean that the two conditions No free lunch with bounded risk and No free lunch with vanishing risk are equivalent. If yes how can I show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different papers published by Freddy Delbaen and Walter Schachermayer in 1994.

#### A general version of the fundamental theorem of asset pricing

They prove a general version of the first fundamental theorem of asset pricing.

- Published in [Mathematische Annalen](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01450498)
- They prove that NFLVR is equivalent to the existence of at least one EMM (``First FTAP''). We need to differentiate three cases though, depending on the price process $S$ which we assume to a be a semimartingale (*Wikipedia and your textbook refer to different versions of the same theorem.*):
- If $S$ is bounded, then an equivalent measure exists under which $S$ is a martingale, see Delbaen and Schachermayer (1994, Theorem 1.1).
- If $S$ is locally bounded, then an equivalent measure exists under which $S$ is a local martingale, see Delbaen and Schachermayer (1994, Corollary 1.2).
- If $S$ is unbounded, then an equivalent measure exists under which $S$ is a sigma-martingale, see Delbaen and Schachermayer (1998, Theorem 1.1).
- In section 6, study the relationship between NFLBR, NFL and NFLVR. The gist is that NFLVR is a special case of NFLBR. Here's a quote from the paper (page 501):

> *The difference between (NFLVR) and (NFLBR) is now clear. In the no
> free lunch with vanishing risk property we deal with sequences such
> that the negative parts tend to 0 uniformly. In the no free lunch with
> bounded risk property we only require these negative parts to tend to
> 0 in probability and remain uniformly bounded!*

- Thus, in general, NFLBR $\Rightarrow$ NFLVR.

The version of the FTAP from Delbaen and Schachermayer is amongst the most general versions of the first FTAP. The original ideas trace back to [Ross (1978)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2352277) and [Harrison and Kreps (1979)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022053179900437).

#### Arbitrage and free lunch with bounded risk for unbounded continuous processes

They give two examples of continuous, but unbounded semimartingales.

- Published in [Mathematical Finance](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9965.1994.tb00063.x)
- Their first example is a market with unique ELMM but which allows arbitrage strategies (NA). Thus, ELMM exists $\nRightarrow$ NA.
- Their second example is a market without arbitrage strategies and without an EMM. NFLBR is satisfied though. Thus, NFLBR $\nRightarrow$ EMM exists. A local martingale measures exists though.
- [Back and Pliska (1991)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/030440689190014K) also give an example of an arbitrage-free market without an EMM.

Comment: So EMM does not imply NFLBR as stated in the theorem in the book?

Comment: This is introduction to option pricing theory by G kallianpur and R karandikar

Comment: @abc sorry if I caused confusion earlier. One shoulnd't answer in a rush. Hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Yeah much clearer.Thanks a  lot for the help